# How does scrapy behave when enough resources are not available

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, scrapy

I am running multiple scrapers using the command line which is an automated process.

Python : 2.7.12
Scrapy : 1.4.0
OS : Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

I want to know how scrapy handles the case when

1. There is not enough memory/cpu bandwidth to start a scraper.
2. There is not enough memory/cpu bandwidth during a scraper run.

I have gone through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

**Anyone answering this, you don't have to know the right answer, if you can point me to the general direction of any resource you know which would be helpful, that would also be appreciated**

Comment: how many scrapers / websites are we talking about here?

Comment: It happened to me, Scrapy process just gets KILLED if enough resources not available on server

Comment: Around 32 scrapers at any instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system kills any process that tries to access more memory than the limit.
Applies to python programs too. and scrapy is no different.

More often than not, bandwidth is the bottleneck in scraping / crawling applications.

Memory would only be a bottleneck if there is a serious memory leak in your application.

Your application would just be very slow if CPU is being shared by many process on the same machine.

Comment: Is there a way to handle situations like this?

Comment: Ground rule for scaling systems: identify the bottleneck, increase its resources to ensure that it ceases to be the bottleneck.

If your ram is an issues: you could either scale it vertically as in, get a larger instance with more ram.
Or you could scale it horizontally: add more instances of the same capacity, dividing the work among them.

Comment: If you choose to scale horizontally, you could start more instances and configure a few spiders to run on them  thus dividing the load. One strategy could be that the largest spiders gets an instance of its own, while the rest of them keep running on the monolithic system. Also, you could choose to take the database out and run it on a separate instance too, with which all the spiders connect.